# What's the difference between using application/csv vs text/csv?

Tags: http, mime-types

What's the difference between using `application/csv` vs `text/csv` as the HTTP Accept Header?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not programming related.

Comment: @DanielA.White It is related because I need to know the distinction in order  to set the appropriate header in my Java service layer.

Comment: Whoever marked this as a duplicate and pointed to the "other" answer is incorrect (at least as far as the current question is stated/edited - it may have been a duplicate originally). The other "answer" does not even mention "application/csv".

Answer (score 80, accepted):

A MIME type is used so software ( like a browser for example ) can know how to handle the data.

If a server says "This data is of type text/csv" the client can understand that can render that data internally, while if the server says "This data is of type application/csv" the client knows that it needs to launch the application that is registered on the OS to open csv files.

text/csv is more generic.

Answer (score 17):

`text/csv` is more appropriate because `application` as a first part implies some interactivity. Your text file not being interactive, it should be announced as text.