# How to set UTF-8 Encoding for a file (Not UTF-8 BOM) in Response stream

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding, quickbooks

I am working with asp.net application with c#. I am trying let user download a file with an IIF extension to support QuickBooks integration.

Step 1: Save the file in web application domain path

[image]

After executing the above lines of code I opened the file using notepad++ and verified the encoding. it showed " Encode in UTF-8" checked[image: File with UTF-8 Encode]

- The same saved file should be downloaded now from the application domain path.
- I have written the following logic to done the downloading file job
  [image: Download file from app domain using Response object]
- Unfortunately after downloading the file from app domain path encoding got changed to UTF-8-BOM.
- I verified in Notepad++

The file encoding should be UTF-8 only. I have changed my code many times but still no luck.

- The Reason behind changing the UTF-8 is I need to feed this file to QuickBooks. Quick books is throwing exception if the encoding is UTF-8-BOM
- Links followed
- [How to set UTF-8 encoding for a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056646/how-to-set-utf-8-encoding-for-a-php-file)
- [How to make sure my created filedownload is UTF-8? (and not UTF-8 without BOM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283518/how-to-make-sure-my-created-filedownload-is-utf-8-and-not-utf-8-without-bom)
- [Response.Write - filename encoding wrong in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434239/response-write-filename-encoding-wrong-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: You can try BinaryWrite or TransmitFile

Comment: @Mertuarez Thank you for the input I will try that now

Comment: @Mertuarez I Tried with TransmitFile but no luck :(

Comment: Remove Charset and ContentEncoding maybe ContentType.
Not sure but content type can be "application/octet-stream" for binary file.

Comment: Not a real answer, but you should know that .IIF files have been deprecated for about 10 years, and are known to cause serious data loss and corruption issues when imported into QuickBooks. You are setting yourself and your users up for a huge failure. Use the QuickBooks APIs instead.